# Recover from DNS NameServer crash

Tags: domain-name-system

I have quite a few domains registered at GoDaddy, and I'm using their nameservers.

Each domain uses 2 nameservers, such as NS10.DOMAINCONTROL.COM. Recently I have encountered a problem where many people emailed in that some of my hosts are inaccessible. After some investigation, I found that all these servers were hosted at the same DOMAINCONTROL.COM server. Some regions in the world failed to resolve my hosts, some managed without any problem.

My question is: is there any recovery from this? What can I do to fix this when this problem happens again? Any tips would be great!

PS. The dns soa started working again (with all propagation) after 4-5 days. In between it was pure hell.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're experiencing problems using somebody else's DNS servers you need to talk to *them* about any issues you're having.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... move your name servers? You could also transfer your domains and move your name servers to another registrar (these are not mutually inclusive).

Comment: GoDaddy is pretty unreliable; if I needed any kind of guaranteed uptime, I'd move them.

Comment: but if I move nameservers during a catastrophe, aren't the results still cached in some dns servers? so nothing would happen, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have a domain example.com, and you (can and should) provide your DNS registrar with the IP addresses of your name servers (not just the domain names of them).  Then when someone looks up example.com, the name servers for the .com domain tell them where to find the name servers for the example.com domain.

So, how long it takes to change the name servers depends on two things.  How quickly your registrar can update the TLD servers (eg or .com) with the new glue record details, and also some negative caching at various local DNS servers for the missing info for your domain.  It used to be that the TLD servers got updated daily for the TLD I mostly deal with.  That may have changed - not sure.  The negative caching should be pretty short.  I'm guessing it might be on the order of 10 mins.